# DllImport fails in C# test (MSTest)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, dllimport

I have a C# project which is a library I reference in one of my C# tests I have:

```
myproj
 |-bin
 +-External
 | |-pHash.dll
 |-main.cs
 |-MyClass.cs
 |-myproj.csproj
```

`pHash.dll` is a Visual C++ library (compiled using a `vcproj` project, so we are talking about Microsoft C++ flavor) called [phash](http://www.phash.org) which exposes this method:

```
int ph_dct_imagehash(const char* file, ulong64& hash);
```

I want to use this method from `MyClass.cs`. So I do this:

```
public class MyClass {
  [DllImport("pHash.dll")]
  static extern int ph_dct_imagehash(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string file,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)] UInt64 hash);
  public MyClass() {...}
  public DoStuff() {
    UInt64 outputValue = 0;
    ph_dct_imagehash("a string", outputValue); // The second parameter should be a pointer in the C++ implementation, not really sure if I am doing it right here
  }
}
```

In my project, I set `External/pHash.dll` to be `Content` and also set it to be `Always copy` in the output folder.

**A possible mistake** As I pointed out, the way I use `ph_dct_imagehash` might be wrong, but this question is about a different error I get, so please skip this and move on :)

`MyClass` is then referenced in one of my tests I execute using `MSText.exe`.

### The error

When I try to run my test which is using that class I get:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'pHash.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

What am I doing wrong?

#### Second attempt

I saw that, when building, actually my `bin` folder looks like this:

```
myproj
 +-bin
   |-External
     |-pHash.dll
```

So I thought I had to change the path to the DLL:

```
public class MyClass {
  [DllImport("External/pHash.dll")]
  static extern int ph_dct_imagehash([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string file, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)] UInt64 hash);
  ...
}
```

But then I get:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'External/pHash.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

### Another question

Is there a (maybe debugging?) tool to understand what path is the CLR trying to follow when encountering `DllImport`? So at least I know where it is trying to look for that dll...

### More info

I have been asked to inspect my dll, so by using [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on `pHash.dll`, I get this error:

> Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for
>   "c:\myuser\testresults\myuser-0131
>   2016-05-06 08_56_50\out\PHASH.DLL" contains errors. The application
>   has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is
>   incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the
>   command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail (14001). Error: At
>   least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
>   Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing
>   export function in an implicitly dependent module. Error: Modules with
>   different CPU types were found. Warning: At least one delay-load
>   dependency module was not found. Warning: At least one module has an
>   unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load
>   dependent module.

This error is also reported in the stack trace when I run my test. I thought it was a message coming from `MSTest` about something else, but now I realize it is a problem of this DLL!

Comment: Are the dependencies of `pHash.dll` installed on the pc you are using? (In particular the vcredist).

Comment: AFAIK `pHash.dll` depends on other 3 dlls which I include in the project in the same way. They get all copied in the output folder of the test in the `TestResult` folder. 

I searched for `vcredist`, but it seems like something that should kick in later. Here the system cannot find the dll in the first place. Interop services should be able to work and locate any dll...

Comment: http://www.dependencywalker.com/ shows anything unusual?

Comment: @Exceptyon: Not really, a few problems on some systemwide dlls but I can see that `pHash.dll` is not listed. Is this tool supposed to show also dlls referenced at runtime via `DllImport`?

Comment: @Exceptyon: I also edited the question

Comment: You should open `pHash.dll` itself in dependency walker. It is not shown as dependency because it is loaded at runtime.

Comment: @Wimmel: Wow actually there are problems... Edited question

Comment: I realize this is a bigger issue and this DLL has problems. I need to update the question with more info probably about the failures...

Comment: few ideas from my dll experience: you could create a managed vc++ dll that calls the unmanaged dll. Ensure everything is built matching 32bit / 64bit and not "any architecture"

Comment: Will try. I could actually get the source code of that dll and when building I get linking problems...

Comment: Usual policy is to get the DLLs into the same dir as the exe. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Even if your DLL is found (sits in the test directory), it is still reported as missing when some of it's dependencies are not found. Make sure you copy the DLL itself and all DLLs it depends on.

Answer (score 0):

You can set select your `dll` in `Solution Explorer`, right click on it and set `BuildAction` to `Content` and `Copy To Output` directory to `CopyAlways`. That way your dll will be copied to application directory and `DllImport` should find it.

Alternatively, use `DllImport`'s `SetDllDirectory` with DLL path before first call of your imported dll

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string yourPath);
```